# dynamically controls with repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm creating dynamically buttons into a repeater like somebody recommend in previous questions I make into a `Page_Init` and I make some conditions but the problem persist, the button don't fire the assigned event

this is the first condition

```
public bool AssignClicked
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["AssignClicked"]);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["AssignClicked"] = value;
            }
        }
```

then this is the code when I make click in the button that create the buttons changing into `true` the condition:

```
protected void DButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssignClicked = true;
        Page_Init(sender, e);
        Page_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

And start the creations of the buttons

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AssignClicked)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

                Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
                var name = Btn_clic.Text;

                List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
                List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

                List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

                var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

                foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
                {
                    Button newButton = new Button();
                    newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                    newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                    newButton.Text = team;
                    newButton.CommandArgument = name;

                    newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

                    Repeater1.Controls.Add(newButton);

                    newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
                }
            }
        }
```

but when I click over the button created this doesn't do anything

Comment: You're missing the point of the repeater - you don't need to dynamically create the buttons, let the template create them.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df6hth3s(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: ok I'm clear in that way, nut how can I assign the text?